# Set nor its compliment contain an uncountable closed set

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Does there exist a set $X$ subset of the real numbers such that no uncountable closed set is contained in $X$ or $X^c$?

Comment: Yes, but you need the axiom of choice.

Comment: How do you choose such a set?

Comment: By transfinite induction.  List all the perfect sets and reals in the same order type.  Build $X$ and $X^c$ inductively, making sure that both sets intersect every perfect set.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: So we are also using the theorem that every uncountable closed set contains a perfect set.  As an aside, are you claiming we *need* the axiom of choice, in the sense that it is consistent that no such $X$ exists?  I know it is consistent (assuming an inaccessible) that every set has the perfect set property, i.e. every uncountable set contains a perfect set, but I don't see how to get from a perfect set to an uncountable closed set.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Perfect sets are closed and uncountable, doesn't this suffice?

Comment: The set of irrational numbers? The complement being countable satisfies. I don't know if there is an uncountable subset of irrationals that form a closed set.

Comment: Yes, there is - take the set of reals between 0 and 1 whose $(2n)$th binary digit is 0 iff n is a power of 2. Clearly this set is closed and uncountable, and because of the bad behavior of the even bits, no number in it can be rational.

Comment: Or there's a general argument that any cocountable set of reals contains a perfect subset of [0, 1]: given any countable set $A=\{a_i: i\in\omega\}$, let $T$ be the set of reals $r$ such that the $(2i)$th binary digit of $r$ is $\not=$ the $(2i)$th binary digit of $a_i$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been answered in the comments.

Comment: I would have been interesting to ask the question with $X$ Borel